# How can I wait for the value from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get values that i save in localStorage but the components render faster and the values are stored later. So for the first time it comes undefined. How can I wait for the values to be stored and than render ?

HERE I GET THE VALUE AFTER IS STORED

The first time comes null because needs time to be stored.

```
function getUsername() {
    const userData = store.get('user');
    const userFullName = userData && JSON.stringify(userData.fullName)
        ? JSON.stringify(userData.fullName).replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1')
        : null
    console.log(userFullName);
    return userFullName;
};
```

HERE I RENDER

```
<AccountFound fullName={getUsername()}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have worked with hooks, but you could try to do the request for the getUserName inside a useEffect and, once the request has finished, store the value inside a useState variable. Then you render the component based on that.

Also, you can try to store in a cost the value of full name and then do:

```
const fullName = getFullName()
fullName ? <Accountfound fullName={fullName} /> : "Loading data..."
```

Comment: No im new in Reactjs and i didn't worked before with hooks.
Can you show me a example how can i implement this ?

Comment: Hope this helps you. https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-golick-72o32?file=/src/App.js.You can check example2 to do it without state

Comment: Thanks for the example but can you make it using functional components ?

Comment: There you have it. I will add another one with hooks just if you want to take a look

Comment: yeah the one with the hooks would help me a lot, thanks

Comment: Added. I'm not sure if it will work 100%, but you can have an idea of how it should be

Comment: yeah but it renders Loading data ... and doesn't show the fullName after (the state doesn't change when the full name is stored)

Comment: Which example are you using?

Comment: the one with the hooks

Comment: check if username gets returned in the  useEffect. Im not able to take a look at the code right now

Comment: Also I don't know if you do some kind of assignment but to get n item from the localstorage you use the localStorage.getItem, not store.get

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would want to get the values from localStorage or cookies as soon as your app boots up and then handle retrieved data as `initialState` for your app state.

I suppose every state management lib has its own way to update components and to perform actions with side effects like `localStorage.setItem`.

If you're not using any lib, you could implement basic [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

```
function makeObservable(target) {
  let listeners = [];
  let value = target;

  function get() {
    return value;
  }

  function set(newValue) {
    if (value === newValue) return;
    value = newValue;
    listeners.forEach((l) => l(val));
  }

  function subscribe(listenerFunc) {
    listeners.push(listenerFunc);
    return () => unsubscribe(listenerFunc);
  }

  function unsubscribe(listenerFunc) {
    listeners = listeners.filter((l) => l !== listenerFunc);
  }

  return {
    get,
    set,
    subscribe,
  };
}
```

Then combine it with `useState` hook by performing `subscribe` on mount:

```
const cachedUser = localStorageOrCookies.get("user");
const userObservable = makeObservable(JSON.parse(cachedUser));

export default function useUser() {
  const [user, setUser] = Reaact.useState(userObservable.get());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return userObservable.subscribe(setUser);
  }, []);

  function set(newUser) {
    userObservable.set(newUser);
    localStorageOrCookies.set("user", JSON.stringify(newUser));
  }

  const actions = {
    setName: name => set({ ...user, name }),
    setAge: age => set({ ...user, age }),
  };

  return [user, actions];
}
```

And now you can use it in your components:

```
import useUser from "./path/to/useUser";

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [user, userActions] = useUser();

  return <>
    <AccountFound fullName={user.name}/>
    <button onClick={() => userActions.setName("Vasya")}>Change name</button>
  </>;
}
```